# HTTP request runtime error

Tags: android, apache, runtime-error

I am trying to make http request.

I am using HTTP Parsing.

Below is the code

```
// Creating HTTP client
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Creating HTTP Post
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");

//array NameValuePair;
// Building post parameters, key and value pair
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "user@gmail.com"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "2222"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "text"));

// Making HTTP Request
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    // writing response to log
    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get runtime error. Below is the Logcat.

It gives some Fatal Exception.

```
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1125)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:857)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at com.custom.functions.citycoupons.CustomDialog$7.onClick(CustomDialog.java:465)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17072)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
07-08 17:17:37.866: E/AndroidRuntime(26380):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-08 17:17:39.336: E/Trace(26551): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

How to fix this issue?
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can not make an HTTP request in the UIThread. Use AsyncTask or other threads.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    String token;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

      // Creating HTTP client
      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

      // Creating HTTP Post
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");

      //array NameValuePair;
      // Building post parameters, key and value pair
      List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
      nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "user@gmail.com"));
      nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "2222"));
      nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "text"));

      // Making HTTP Request
      try {
          HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

          // writing response to log
          Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());

      } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
          // writing exception to log
          e.printStackTrace();

      } catch (IOException e) {
          // writing exception to log
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

    }
}.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Asyn Task for sending the HTTP request. as you are making the request  on the main thread, hence it is giving you the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` on your Sticky Mode.

Answer (score 0):

After 2.2, you cannot call network operations on main thred, that's why it is showing `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. To fix this issue, use AsyncTask class

For example,

Call this from main thread i.e after setContentView(),

```
new LongTask(your_activity.this).execute();


private class LongTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>
{

   protected void doInBackground(Void... params)  // inside this method do your network operations
   {

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

// Creating HTTP Post
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url");

//array NameValuePair;
// Building post parameters, key and value pair
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
     nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "user@gmail.com"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "2222"));
    nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("text", "text"));

// Making HTTP Request
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    // writing response to log
    Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());
    return response.toString();

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
   return "Error"
} catch (IOException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
     return "Error"
}
   }


 protected void onPostExecute(String s)
{
     super.onPostExecute(s);
     // here with String "s", you can access the result you got from service
}   
}
```

Please check [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I tried implementing above, still same error I get :(